# Self Join without duplicates

Tags: sql, postgresql, self-join

I have a table that represents possible connections between stations of a public transport service. It looks like this:

```
trip_id | station_id | sequence
--------+------------+---------
  1     |   A        |   1
  1     |   B        |   2
  1     |   C        |   3
  2     |   C        |   1
  2     |   B        |   2
  2     |   A        |   3
```

Now I want to select all possible connections between two stations without duplicates, i. e. I just need the connection A->B and not B->A.

I came up with this Join but unfortunately there are duplicates:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c1.station_id, c2.sation_id 
FROM connections c1, connections c2 
WHERE c1.trip_id = c2.trip_id AND c1.sequence = c2.sequence-1
```

Comment: I take it a "connection" is two stations appears adjacently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest method is a variation on your code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT LEAST(c1.station_id, c2.station_id) as station_id1,
       GREATEST(c1.station_id, c2.station_id) as station_id2
FROM connections c1 JOIN
     connections c2 
     c1.trip_id = c2.trip_id AND c1.sequence = c2.sequence - 1
```